# injecting <xsl:param> into <command>

Tags: xslt, param

I have `<xsl:param name="file"/>` at the top of my XSLT file.
I have a section `<Command>`, that is supposed to create a file with the name given in `<param>` (file_name).
I tried

```
<Command>echo. > $file</Command>
```

but it creates a file called $file.

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<Command> echo > <xsl:value-of select="$file"/></Command>`.

Comment: @Battle_Slug - It sounds like this was the answer you were looking for. You should accept it by clicking the checkmark to the left.

Comment: @Daniel Haley, thank you for guiding me, I just forgot.